# Keyboard shortcut to open an application in new workspace in Gnome Shell 3.2

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome

I am running Gnome Shell 3.2 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I generally launch application from Meta-key, followed by a few characters, followed by up-down arrows, followed by Enter. The applications launch in the same workspace.

Is there a keyboard shortcut so that I can open the application in a new workspace? If not by default, is there any way in which it can be done? (Alt-Enter or Shift-Enter, etc)

Comment: Is it something that can not be done??

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible, unless someone writes an extension for it.

According to the [GnomeShell Cheat Sheet](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet) the closest you can get to this functionality is to launch the application, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to move it to another workspace.

Comment: Sad. That would have been a useful keyboard shortcut.